# NextJS Build Error: "Error occurred prerendering page "/admin/prices""

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend, next.js13, next-auth

I try to build my NextJS app.

**When I launch `npm run build` I face an error:**

```bash
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000
at getCourses (/Users/vladislavobedkov/Desktop/code/kingcode/client/.next/server/app/admin/prices/page.js:859:15)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async PricesPage (/Users/vladislavobedkov/Desktop/code/kingcode/client/.next/server/app/admin/prices/page.js:866:21)
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000
at fetchReviews (/Users/vladislavobedkov/Desktop/code/kingcode/client/.next/server/app/admin/reviews/list/page.js:645:15)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async ReviewListPage (/Users/vladislavobedkov/Desktop/code/kingcode/client/.next/server/app/admin/reviews/list/page.js:649:21)

Error occurred prerendering page "/admin/prices". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000
at getCourses (/Users/vladislavobedkov/Desktop/code/kingcode/client/.next/server/app/admin/prices/page.js:859:15)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async PricesPage (/Users/vladislavobedkov/Desktop/code/kingcode/client/.next/server/app/admin/prices/page.js:866:21)

Error occurred prerendering page "/admin/reviews/list". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000
```

The interesting thing is that sometimes errors occur only in 1-2 pages out of 3.

**Here is my `admin/reviews/list`-page code:**

```js
import { errorCatch } from "@/app/api/helper";
import { ReviewsList } from "@/components/Reviews/ReviewsList/ReviewsList";
import { ReviewService } from "@/services/review/review.service";
import { Metadata } from "next";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
    title: "Список отзывов - King Code",
}

const fetchReviews = async() => {
    try {
        const reviews = await ReviewService.getAll();
        return reviews;
    } catch(err) {
        throw new Error(errorCatch(err));
    }
};

export default async function ReviewListPage() {
    const reviews = await fetchReviews();

    return <ReviewsList reviews={reviews}/>
}
```

When I start my project with `npm run dev` and then launch `npm run build` all these errors disappear. However, I face another one: `cannot find module for page "/_error"`.

I tried to remove my `/node_modules`- and `/.next`- directories.

Comment: This error occur because you are using `http://localhost:3000/something` which is wrong because localhost is not present on `npm run build`

Comment: What url should I use? I use next api route

Comment: please share your api code then, i will help u

Comment: Here is an example (with review api): https://codepen.io/vladikEmmet/pen/zYyWzXE
I'm not sure I understand correctly what you are asking of me. I'm just learning NextJS

Comment: I forgot to say that I already have a domain name for this project. But when I try to build the project, in this case requests to it also fail for obvious reasons.